# Insert a new row between two consecutive rows in a CSV file in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I have a CVS table like this:

> ```
>  1st row: Types, Categories, Calculation
>  2nd row: Type1, Category1, Calculation1
>  3rd row: "   ", Category2, Calculation2
>  4th row: "   ", Category3, Calculation3
>  5th row: Type2, Category4, Calculation4
>  6th row: "   ", Category5, Calculation5
>  7th row: "   ", Category6, Calculation6
>  8th row: Type3, Category7, Calculation7
>  9th row: "   ", Category8, Calculation8
> ```

I have code that has the user input a type, category and a numerical value separated by a single comma followed by a space.  I was wondering how I could insert a row below the last row of the type without changing either if the inputted type matches one of existing types and the inputted category does not match any of the categories within the type. i.e.:

> ```
> Input: Type1, Category5, Calculation9
> ```

Goal:

```
 1st row:  Types, Categories, Calculation
 2nd row:  Type1, Category1, Calculation1
 3rd row:  "   ", Category2, Calculation2
 4th row:  "   ", Category3, Calculation3
 5th row:  "   ", Category5, Calculation9
 6th row:  Type2, Category4, Calculation4
 7th row:  "   ", Category5, Calculation5
 8th row:  "   ", Category6, Calculation6
 9th row:  Type3, Category7, Calculation7
 10th row: "   ", Category8, Calculation8
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?